# Page ribbon is visible to members of the Members Group(contribute) in a document set

Tags: 2013

I have all users as contributors in a site collection.
It means they can edit, add, delete documents and pages.

However, I have a document library, which main content type is a document set.
The users can create document sets, remove etc.

However when they go to the document set page, there is an option on the top right to edit thepage, and the PAGE ribbon is still visible.

How can I disallow this, without removing the edit permissions of the library?

Something I just noticed also, is when you click on edit page on the ribbon, nothing happens, so the actual members dont have the righ to edit the welcome set page which is logical to me, as I see the a document set welcome page as a system page which should not be modified by anyone.

The question is how can if possible, to remove the Page Ribbon in the document set welcome page?   Is this a Sharepoint 2013 bug?

Pls see screenshot[image]

Comment: Have you tried breaking the inheritance? For example, give them read rights on the page, but contributor rights in the containing library.

Comment: in which page? thats the problem, it creates a docsethomepage.aspx for every document set.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your statement. This question seems similar to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104137/sharepoint-permissions-user-should-able-to-submit-the-form-but-not-able-to-edi

Maybe a custom permission level without inheritance will actually work.

Comment: this doesnt solve my question. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide the page tab, you could do with javascript and css.
Here is 2 different solutions:
http://johanolivier.blogspot.in/2011/12/show-or-hide-sharepoint-ribbon-tab.html

http://blog.concurrency.com/sharepoint/hide-sharepoint-ribbon/

Comment: Solution 1 seems good, but doesnt explain how can I hide the page tab only on Document Sets.  Is  this standard SP2013 functionality? Why an end user would see the page ribbon in a document set welcome page, if the edit page button does not even do anything.